# Relative FPGA Footprint of ARM Cortex M3 vs. MicroBlaze

Tags: fpga, arm, microblaze

I may have missed it, but does anyone have experience with the relative resource consumption of a MicroBlaze versus the core for an ARM Cortex M3 IP?  It seems like there should be a ballpark comparison of CLBs, BRAMs, and DSP48Es consumed.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question here. Stack exchange is not a discussion forum.

Comment: a MicroBlaze is a FPGA optimized design, a ARM Cortex M3 IP is a silicon (ASIC) optimized design. Using a silicon optimized design in a FPGA will use more resources and you also can assume lower maximum clock speed...

Comment: I was looking for a comparison in terms of the range of resources, since it appears that Xinlinx is pushing the ARM Cortex M3 core as an alternative to the MicroBlaze.  It clearly seems the former will use more resources, but I can't find even ballpark estimates. Not looking for an opinion. Looking for some specific pointer to the info or someone who has made this comparison.

Comment: Try posting FPGA QUESTION [HERE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125912/fpga?referrer=M2EwM2FlOWQwMWY3MmExMzFhMGYzYjdhMmZjNWIzYzI2ZTZiZjhmNGU4Y2M4M2JjNDgxZjQyYTIyMzA2MWUwNzX3hnbYNR7EdlfF6m4rBq-JYXjqFwvBDZB5QkiDqKuf0)